# How to edit a instance variable?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and as I was doing an assignment for class, I got stuck using **init** method.

```
class Customer(object):
    def __init__(self, number, name):

        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.orders = []
        
        
    def addorder(self, order):
        self.orders.extend(order) 
        return self.orders

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.orders)


Customer('308','John').addorder((1,2,3,4))

print(Customer('308','John'))
```

The output is an empty list [].

I want the output to be [1,2,3,4]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're creating the object twice. Assign `Customer('308', 'John')` to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that each time you "call" a class, you instantiate a new object (this is why in many languages other than Python, this actually requires the keyword `new`). So, in your example, you're instantiating two different objects (that don't share their properties). Instead, you should save them in a variable:

```py
customer = Customer("308", "John")
customer.addorder((1, 2, 3, 4))
print(customer)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have two `Customer` objects. I.e. your print line:

```
print(Customer('308','John'))
```

Is creating a new `Customer` object with a number of `'308'` and a name of `'John'`. It's completely unrelated to the customer on the previous line.

To fix this, you should assign your first object to a variable (think of it like a handle, that lets you access the object), and then print that:

```
john = Customer('308','John')
john.addorder((1,2,3,4))
print(john)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating two instances of the class

```
class Customer(object):
    def __init__(self, number, name):

        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.orders = []
        
        
    def addorder(self, order):
        self.orders.extend(order) 
        return self.orders

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.orders)


customer = Customer('308','John')
customer.addorder((1,2,3,4))

print(customer)
```